# Why are IVP defined by continuous functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

One normally defines an initial value problem by the following parameters:

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be an open set,
>   $(t_{0},x_0)\in D$ and $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ a continuous
>   function. We consider the initial value problem given by $ (P)
>  \begin{cases} x' = f(t,x) \\ x(t_{0}) = x_0 \end{cases} $

Why do we impose that $f$ is a continuous function?

In other words, what are the theoretical motivations for it (of course I'd say it is easier to work with this)? What happens if we remove this condition? (for instance I just discovered [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For initial value problems

$$\begin{cases} x' = f(t,x) \\ x(t_{0}) = x_0 \end{cases}$$

continuity of $f(t,x)$ implies the existence of a solution and continuity of $$\partial f/\partial x$$ implies uniqueness.

Comment: Is there a name for this theorem?

Comment: @goblin for the existence part it is peano's theorem and for uniqueness is picard-lindelof (if im not mistaken)

Comment: what is the situation if we remove the continuity condition?

Comment: Without continuity of $f(t,x)$ we may or may not get a solution.